# How to set Start Date for Auto-Schedule in JIRA Advanced Roadmaps?

Tags: jira

When I use Auto-Schedule in JIRA Advanced Roadmaps for

- an Epic with four stories where some stories some have subtasks
- where every subtask has estimated hours
- no sprint is assigned to the Epic, Stories or Sub-Tasks
- where the Epic is assigned a Start Date of 6/1/2022 (in the Roadmaps field configured for "Start Date")

The proposed schedule generated doesn't begin on 6/1/2022. Instead the next business day is used. In this example it starts on 4/26/2022.

How do you tell Auto-schedule to start on a specific date?

[image: Roadmap Tasks]

[image: Roadmap Auto Scheduled Tasks]

Answer (score 0):

The only way I know of setting a start date will affect all epics:

1. Go into your advanced roadmap
2. Click on the three dots right from your roadmap name
3. Click on "Configure"
4. By default the "Scheduling" settings should open

There you can set the start date.

---

When you are looking to provide a start date for an Epic/Issue, then this is not possible at the moment: https://jira.atlassian.com/browse/JSWCLOUD-22406?actionOrder=desc